# KVM and Libvirt messing on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: virtualization

I'm trying to run KVM on Raspberry Pi 2. Through Google I found that Cortex-A7 used in RPi2 supports virtualization extensions which needs GIC(Generic Interrupt Controller) for interrupt routing/control but Raspberry SoC uses a different modified Interrupt Controller.

I found this awesome post that showed how to hack RPi2 to run KVM virtualization and by following it, I successfully ran a VM using qemu-system-arm.

I tried to run a simple 'CirrOS' using 'virt-install' command after and nothing shows up after the 'escape character' line.

```
virt-install --connect=qemu:///system --name=cirros --ram=256 --vcpus=1 --disk path=cirros-0.3.2-x86_64-disk.img,format=qcow2 --import --network network:default --nographics
```

I'm trying to verify if 'libvirt' works okay which I need later in my project. I'm a beginner in this area and I hope someone can guide me. I'm not entirely sure if I should post this question in here or unix.stackexchange.com.

Sources:
https://lists.gt.net/xen/users/369667

http://blog.flexvdi.es/2015/03/17/enabling-kvm-virtualization-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/

Thanks

Comment: Is that guest a x86 image? I think you might stuggle to get that working on the ARM chip on the RPi. QEMU does have some emulation capacity but I think translating x86 to ARM and back might be a little sluggish. You may also need to get hold of some qemu libs to support that translation.

Comment: @tobyd I tried an arm version of CirrOS too, same result. And I'm confused about one other thing, QEMU with KVM disabled can be done for arm based images on RPi, right? like underlying hardware shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: That should be the case - qemu on the Pi in pure emulation might be unusably slow and for x86 you'd need some extra libs. Those instructions appear to only be for ARM guest virtualisation, worth checking the logs at `~/.virtinst/virt-install.log` to see whats causing problems. Perhaps try virtualising the stock raspbian-lite image?